# Desativar o CSRF token do laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, csrf

No laravel 5.2 quero desativar CSRF em uma rota, pois estou utilizando o pagseguro (michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro) e quero trabalhar com o retorno automático.

Já tentei adicionar a rota no array de exceção no arquivo App\Http\MiddlewareVerifyCsrfToken

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier{
    protected $except = [
       'pagseguro/notification',
    ]; 
}
```

Já tentei excluir e comentar o VerifyCsrfToken no App\Http\kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
       //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
```

Nenhum dos métodos funcionaram, continuo recebendo o erro abaixo:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219
```

Comment: Será que não é por causa do espaço em `protected $except = [
       ' pagseguro/notification',
    ]; `? Esse erro não parace ser do token, acho que a ser do token seria qualquer coisa como `tokenmissmatch exception...`

Comment: isso foi um erro de digitação, no arquivo estava sem o espaço. ja alterei aqui também, mas nada de funcionar ainda.

Comment: Não exclua no kernel. Na deixe só no except do middleware

Comment: Eu acho que o erro não tem mesmo a haver com com o token. acabei de testar com a rota que não quero no middleware e funcionou 5 estrelas. Eu acho que nas rotas pode estar a baralhar post/get nessa rota

Comment: Foi a primeira coisa que fiz e não rolou, depois tentei comentar o VerifyCsrfToken tb não rolou, tentei excluir  o VerifyCsrfToken tb não foi.

Comment: criei uma outra rota de teste só para isso e não foi, vou tentar instalar o laravel zerado e testar.

Comment: muito estranho. comigo funcionou.. E todos os artigos que leio dizem que é assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está entendendo errado. A exceção `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` é disparada quando você tenta acessar uma rota `POST` via método `GET` (ou qualquer outro método, só estou exemplificando).

A exceção que é disparada quando o token é inválido, é `TokenMismatchException`.

Então, não há nada de errado. O problema talvez seja outro.

Comment: Wallace Maxters de fato o problema no controle \laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\NotificationController@notification direcionei para outro controle que criei para testa e funcionou.

Comment: Ótima explicação sobre os diferentes tipos de exception, isso é um detalhes que sempre temos que notar.

Answer (score 3):

A solução que estou usando em uma api restful no site que participo:

Coloquei as rotas exceções no arquivo:

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

(todas as demais rotas fazem parte do site, ou seja, "não restful")

Ficando assim:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        "api",
        "api/user",
        "api/products",
        "api/whatever......",
    ];
}
```

Comment: Funcionou para mim. Mas tem como informar a rota ao invés do URI?

Comment: Há como eu amo esse stackoverflow! <3